# Causing a hardware failure via a software program?

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a virus melt the CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/54385/can-a-virus-melt-the-cpu)

I want to destroy my Windows PC by running a software program.  By destroy I mean: Causing the CPU or RAM to melt, causing the hard drive to crash, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Someone's been watching too many movies. These aren't the days of Commodores and CGA graphics anymore.

Comment: Thermite inside the case with a detonator connected to the serial port. Send the right string and everything melts :)

Comment: YOUR windows pc??? :D If it is for real your pc, and if it works, you should consider to donate it, instead of destroying it...

Comment: On a more serious note: Can you add hardware?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/54385/can-a-virus-melt-the-cpu

Comment: Jack Bauer could. Well, actually he would call Chloe and she would do it for him.

Comment: @emgee: you're using a USB-to-serial converter, right?  or does your motherboard have a serial header?  i haven't seen an actual soldered-on serial *port* in years...

Comment: Vote to move to MythOverflow.com

Comment: I once destroyed a CRT by booting OpenSuSE at 1600x1200.

Comment: Jack Bauer could...I'm sure that Marshall Flinkman could do it in a breeze!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Not anymore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_poke).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is possible, as the [recent nVidia incident](http://www.nvidia.com/object/196.75_customer_support.html) showed. Basically, a bug in the graphic card driver would drive the fan too slowly, which could eventually lead to damage of the GPU. So, speaking of drivers, it is possible, even though modern hardware *should* have built-in protection against that.

Answer (score 1):

## Can't be done.

Simplest answer I can give you. Without hardware / firmware modifications on all of the devices it is impossible. You can't just make your computer **blow up** no matter what you see in movies.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer- no. You can render the mobo unusable with a failed flashing though windows though.